# debugging containerised python web app

Tags: python, docker, wsgi, docker-container, turbogears2

I have made this first docker container, and it works as per the `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM python:3.5-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install gcc mono-mcs && \
        apt-get -y install vim && \
        apt-get -y install nano && \
            rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p /statics/js

VOLUME ["/statics/"]

WORKDIR /statics/js

COPY requirements.txt /opt/requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r /opt/requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["python", "/statics/js/app.py"]
```

after running this command:

> docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -v
>   ~/Development/my-Docker-builds/pythonReact/statics/:/statics/ -d 
>   ciasto/pythonreact:v2

and when I open the page `localhost:8080` i get error:

```
A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.
```

but if I run [this application](https://github.com/sanfx/pythonReact/blob/master/statics/js/app.py) normally, i.e. not containerised directly on my host machine: it works fine.

So I want to know what is causing server error. How do I debug a python app that runs via container to know what is causing it to not work. or what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainly, this:

```
config.paths['static_files'] = 'statics'
```

Should be:

```
config.paths['static_files'] = '/statics'
```

---

I've got your application up and running with your 'Hello World'

Did these changes:

1) The mentioned `config.paths['static_files'] = '/statics'`

2) This Dockerfile (**removed VOLUME**)

```
FROM python:3.5-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install gcc mono-mcs && \
    apt-get -y install vim && \
    apt-get -y install nano && \
        rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY requirements.txt /opt/requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r /opt/requirements.txt

COPY ./statics/ /statics/
COPY app.py /app/app.py
WORKDIR /statics/js

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["python", "/app/app.py"]
```

3) Moved the non-static app.py to a proper place: root of the project.

4) Run with: `docker build . -t pyapp`, then `docker run -p 8080:8080 -it pyapp`

You should see `Serving on port 8080...` from terminal output. And `Hello World` in browser.

I've forked your Github project and did a [pull-request](https://github.com/sanfx/pythonReact/pull/1).

---

Edit:

If you need make changes when you develop, run the container with a volume to override the app that is packed in the image. For example:

```
docker run -v ./static/js/:/static/js -p 8080:8080 -it pyapp
```

You can have as many volumes as you want, but the app is already packed in the image and ready to push somewhere.

Comment: Quick question: why would you pack the whole app inside the container ?

Comment: It's one of the main features of docker: pack applications in images and deliver them. If you need to develop and get changes refreshed quickly, you can `docker run` with a volume. I will add it to the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) to debug Python code in CLI. To achieve this, you just have to import `pdb` and call `pdb.set_trace()` where you would like to have a breakpoint in your Python code. Basically you have to insert the following line where you want a breakpoint:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Then you have to run your Python code interactively.

You could do that by running `bash` interactively in your container with

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -v ~/Development/my-Docker-builds/pythonReact/statics/:/statics/ ciasto/pythonreact:v2 /bin/bash
```

and then running manually your app with

```
root@5910f24d0d8a:/statics/js# python /statics/js/app.py
```

When the code will reach the breakpoint, it will pause and a prompt will be shown where you can type commands to inspect your execution.
For more detail about the available commands, you can give a look at [the pdb commands documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands).

---

Also, I noted that you are building your image using the `python:3.5-slim` base image which is a (very) light Python image which does not include all is commonly included in a Python distribution.

From [the Python images page](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/):

> This image does not contain the common packages contained in the default tag and **only contains the minimal packages needed to run python**. Unless you are working in an environment where only the python image will be deployed and you have space constraints, **we highly recommend using the default image** of this repository.

Maybe using the standard `python:3.5` image instead would solve your issue.

Comment: ok thanks I will give it a try. I  didn't thought I can just jump into the same container and use debugger.

Comment: actually I am fully aware of debugger but whats bothering me is tat the app works if I run on host mac OS machine directly but not on Linux container

Comment: following your steps: I get this message:
`Default renderer not in renders, automatically switching to kajiki
app_globals not provided and lib.app_globals.Globals is not available.
helpers not provided and lib.helpers is not available.`

Comment: you are using the `python:3.5-slim` image as your Dockerfile base. Did you try with the standard `python:3.5`?

Comment: tried didn't helped also tried python 3.4 which is most compatible and tested on with `dukpy` required for rendering javascript. still didn't work, however I am on `Debian 4.9.2-10` with `gcc version 4.9.2` .

Answer (score 0):

As a quick tip for debugging containerized applications. If your application is failing with container crashed/stopped. Just launch the container image with `CMD/ENTRYPOINT` as  `/bin/bash` then manually start the application once you have the container shell you can debug the application as per normal Linux system. `CMD` is straightforward to override as per `ENTRYPOINT` just use `--entrypoint` flag with `docker run` command.